# Transferring data to a test table

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

There is a table contact_history with 1.244.000.000 number of data (from 04.03.22-05.06.2022) and with fields contact_dt and contact_dttm. I tried to transfer all the data to test using contact_dt with script:

```
**DECLARE  
dat date;
begin
dat:= TO_DATE('04.03.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy');  
while dat<= TO_DATE('05.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') loop 
INSERT /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(16)*/
INTO CONTACT_HISTORY_TEST ct
SELECT -- + parallel(16) 
     ch.sas_contact_id,
     ch.contact_source,
     ch.client_id,
     ch.contact_dttm,
     ch.contact_dt,
     ch.sas_contact_error_desc,
     ch.sas_contact_status
FROM CONTACT_HISTORY ch
WHERE ch.contact_dt = dat;
commit;
dat:= dat+1;
end loop;
end;**
```

There is such a problem that when **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CONTACT_HISTORY_TEST** shows only 1.200.000.000 data in the test table, when in general table 1.244.000.000.

And there is such a moment that when checking

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CONTACT_HISTORY 
WHERE CONTACT_DT>= TO_DATE('04.03.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
AND CONTACT_DT<= TO_DATE('05.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CONTACT_HISTORY_TEST
WHERE CONTACT_DT>= TO_DATE('04.03.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND CONTACT_DT<= TO_DATE('05.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

In both tables, there are 1.200.000.000 data, please tell me where the remaining 44 million data have gone and how can I completely transfer the data from the table or how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that `contact_dt` column contains date values that have time component; for example, it isn't just `04.03.2021`, but `04.03.2021 13:23:45`.

Code you posted handles "start" of the period correctly as `04.03.2021` actually represents `04.03.2021 00:00:00`.

However, the last day of that period isn't handled correctly - you're missing (almost) the whole last day because you *copied* only rows whose `contact_dt` is equal to `05.06.2022 00:00:00`. What about eg. `05.06.2022 08:32:13`?

Therefore, modify *something*. If `contact_dt` column is indexed, you shouldn't truncate it, so the simplest option is to change this

```
while dat <= TO_DATE('05.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') loop
```

to

```
while dat <  TO_DATE('06.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') loop
```

---

As @APC commented, `where` clause should then also be fixed to

```
where ch.contact_dt >= dat and ch.contact_dt < dat + 1
```

---

To verify number of rows and date values, run the following code in both schemas and then post the result (edit the question, not as a comment):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

select min(contact_dt) min_dat, max(contact_dt) max_dat, count(*) cnt 
from contact_history;
```

Comment: If your guess is correct (and I suspect it is) the Seeker will also need to change the WHERE clause to something like `WHERE ch.contact_dt >= dat and  ch.contact_dt < dat + 1`.

Comment: The number of data received did not change, the number remained the same 1.200.000.000
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DWH_EXPORT_E01.EXP_MA_CONTACT_HISTORY_6M
WHERE CONTACT_DT >= TO_DATE('04.03.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND CONTACT_DT <  TO_DATE('06.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')

Comment: I'll try using method as @APC said, thanks

Comment: @SultanZhubaniyazov - so what was the query you ran which told you CONTACT_HISTORY had  1.244.000.000 rows? Obviously not the same query which is telling you it only has  1.200.000.000 rows.

Comment: select count(*) from contact_history shows 1.244.000.000 data @apc

Comment: That's the total number of rows (as there's no WHERE clause). What does `select min(contact_dt), max(contact_dt) from contact_history` return?

Comment: min date of contact_dt is 04.03.2022 and max date is 05.06.2022 in contact history @littlefoot

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of edited answer; run that piece of code in both schemas and post the result.

Comment: @SultanZhubaniyazov - Prediction: you have 44 million rows where `contact_dt` IS NULL

Comment: @APC I solved my problem by taking CONTACT_DTTM and selecting the range CONTACT_DTTM > 03/04/22 AND CONTACT_DTTM <= 06/05/2022 since they don't have null values. I could have just added empty contact_dts with empty values, but I got a strange ORA error.